# Stomp JS: Getting error "Unknown Destination" when sending a message

Tags: mqtt, stomp, stompjs

I am trying to send message from StompJS to MQTT broker.
So far I am able to connect to the broker.
However, when I try to send a message using following command

```
  stompClient.publish({
       destination: `/test`,
       binaryBody: data, 
       headers: {
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
       })
```

It gives me error "Unknown destination" on the onStompError callback. And they payload has no destination property.

However If I submit like below. Then it automatically adds makes the destination as /queue/test and sends successfully, even though its not the correct destination at all.

```
stompClient.publish({
       destination: `test`,
       binaryBody: data, 
       headers: {
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
       })
```

Comment: What message broker are you using?

Comment: I don't have exact details but it is MQTT broker.

Comment: There are lots of MQTT brokers so specifics would be helpful here. Does the broker have logging that would indicate what data is coming over the wire such that you could tell whether the `/queue/` was being added by the client or not?

Comment: Your question doesn't really explain _why_ adding `/queue/` is a problem. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm not sure that the MQTT broker is relevant here?. Your code appears to be sending a message to a STOMP broker; as per [the spec](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html) "STOMP treats this destination as an opaque string and no delivery semantics are assumed by the name of a destination". As such, if I am reading this right, you need to provide info on your stomp broker and its configuration (and remove the MQTT tag as its irrelevant).